# XML Parsing using Java not getting any Response

Tags: java, android, xml, httpresponse

am trying to get the XML file from a URL but am getting no Response and the code stops later because the String xml is null, can you tell me whats the problem ?

```
public String getXmlFromUrl(String url) {
 String xml = null;

    try {


        DefaultHttpClient httpClient = new DefaultHttpClient();
        HttpPost httpPost = new HttpPost(url);
        HttpResponse httpResponse = httpClient.execute(httpPost);
                    // I printed the response here but I got nothing ! 
        HttpEntity httpEntity = httpResponse.getEntity();
        xml = EntityUtils.toString(httpEntity);
                    return xml;


    } catch (Exception e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
```

**Please be specific in you answers I appreciate your help**

Comment: Did you checked URL in browser if it return some data?

Comment: did you try printing the 'xml' ?   xml = EntityUtils.toString(httpEntity);

Comment: @DmytroDanylyk yes I did and its working properly

Comment: @rahul yes and am getting nothing

Comment: NetworkOnMainThreadException is catched in catch block and xml stays null ...

Comment: Better try [this](http://www.androidhive.info/2011/11/android-xml-parsing-tutorial/) example

Comment: Did you added Internet permission to manifest?

Comment: @SpK i took the code from ur link

Comment: @DmytroDanylyk yes first thing i checked

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Why you are using HTTPPost?? You are not sending any data Even. Try with HttpGet.

Try This :

```
public String getXmlFromUrl(String url) throws Exception {
    return new AsyncTask<String, Void, String>() {
        @Override
        protected String doInBackground(String... params) {
            String xml = null;
            try {
                DefaultHttpClient httpClient = new DefaultHttpClient();
                HttpGet httpPost = new HttpGet(params[0]);
                HttpResponse httpResponse = httpClient.execute(httpPost);
                // I printed the response here but I got nothing !
                HttpEntity httpEntity = httpResponse.getEntity();
                xml = EntityUtils.toString(httpEntity);
                Log.i("DEMO", xml);

            } catch (Exception e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
            return xml;
        }
    }.execute(url).get();

}
```

Comment: but this " Document doc = parser.getDomElement(xml); // getting DOM element" is not working anymore

Comment: this is a funny thing to do, create an asynctask and wait for the answer in the same method. I don't see why would you do that ?

Answer (score 0):

Try to start your code from separate thread e.g.

```
 new Thread(new Runnable()
 {

    @Override
    public void run()
    {
        // TODO your code here

    }
  }).start();
```

Answer (score 0):

try this:

```
try {

    items = new ArrayList<String>();

    XmlPullParserFactory factory = XmlPullParserFactory.newInstance();
    factory.setNamespaceAware(true);
    XmlPullParser xpp = factory.newPullParser();
    xpp.setInput(new InputStreamReader(
            getUrlData(" url")));

    while (xpp.getEventType() != XmlPullParser.END_DOCUMENT) {
        Log.i(TAG, "doc started");
        if (xpp.getEventType() == XmlPullParser.START_TAG) {
            if (xpp.getName().equals("entry")) {
                items.add(xpp.getAttributeValue(0));
            }
        }
        xpp.next();

    }
} catch (Throwable t) {
    Toast.makeText(this, "Request failed: " + t.toString(),
            Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
}
```

Answer (score 0):

for geturldata()

```
public InputStream getUrlData(String url) throws URISyntaxException,
    ClientProtocolException, IOException {

DefaultHttpClient client = new DefaultHttpClient();
HttpGet method = new HttpGet(new URI(url));
HttpResponse res = client.execute(method);
return res.getEntity().getContent();
```

}

Answer (score 0):

You should understand **Exceptions**. The reason xml is `null` is because 'something' went wrong. This threw an `Exception`, probably with a good description of what went wrong. When this happens, the `Exception` is thrown 'up' until someone handles it.

Every subclass of `Exception` has a different 'flavor' and is thrown in specific cases. This enables you to 'react' on errors. For instance, you could tell the user what went wrong, or log something for debugging sake.

In your case, you 'catch' all exceptions in a single place, when an exception occurs,  the code after `catch (Exception e)` is executed. You do nothing here but printing out some stuff (this will appear orange in your LogCat). Then you continue as if nothing happened. But xml will be null, which is bad for your program, and you apparently didn't notice the LogCat entry because your program crashes at a later point.

This time, Eldhose M Babu solved your problem. Next time, when something else goes wrong (and a lot can go wrong in htttp requests), your program will show the same behavior. Try and read up on exceptions and be careful when you handle them too silently.